# How to match words in curly braces?

Tags: regex, sublimetext

I want to replace some text in sublime. I have some text

```
{{abcd dog cat}}
```

and I want to make them become

```
{abcd dog cat}
```

I cannot directly replace `{{` to `{` because some `{{` is necessary in my text.

I know using regular expression can achieve my purpose. But I don’t know how to use it.

Now I use `{$1}` to replace
`\{{(\w+)}\}`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Replace `\w+` with `[^{}]+`

Comment: In addition to @WiktorStribiżew comment, this is because `\w` is a shorthand for `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, that doesn't include whitespaces. In your example, there are whitespaces.

Comment: If you only want to replace those with exactly two opening and closing braces and where words inside, you can further surround the new expression by lookarounds and add word boundaries inside on both sides like this: [`(?<!{){({\b[^}{]+\b})}(?!})`](https://regex101.com/r/pB46Bg/1/) and replace with `$1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `\w` will not match a space. You can match the content between the `{{` and `}}` using for example `.+?` and place the capturing group between the first and the second curly brace.

In the replacement use `$1`

```
{({.+?})}
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/G2sLPI/1)

If you only want to match word characters with a single space between the words, you could use match 1+ word chars and repeat 0 or more times 1+ word chars preceded by a space:

```
{({\w+(?: \w+)*})}
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vmycHf/1)